# Where is the error in tag(a)?

Tags: xhtml-1.0-strict, html4

this is my first year in html courses, i'm using HTML 4.01 Strict/XHTML 1.1
Where is the error in this code??

```
<a href="http://www.upv.es" onclick="target='_blank';">
<img src="http://politube.upv.es/templates/imagenes_cabecera/escudo.gif"/>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you don't provide us with information about what you expect and what is not working. If you try to open the link in a new Tab, you'll have to change

```
 onclick="target='_blank';"
```

to

```
target="_blank"
```

Otherwise, you'll be just setting a JavaScript variable `target` to the string value `_blank`.